# How to get html text from a relative element using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, parent

So I'm trying to get the specific text inside an HTML tag which is a relative from it. The thing is that I have multiple Parents, which means I have multiple calls and diferent texts wanted.

As an example:

```
    <parent>
       <child>
           <grandchild class="wanted">Text</grandchild>
           <grandchild></grandchild>
       </child>
       <child>
           <grandchild></grandchild>
           <grandchild></grandchild>
       </child>
       <child>
           <grandchild class="calling"></grandchild>
           <grandchild></grandchild>
       </child>
   </parent>
```

And my script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calling").click(function(){
       var message = $(this).parent().siblings(".wanted").html();
    });
});
```

The thing is that I cannot get the Text wanted, and I don't know if I have to parse or not, even when I've already tried so.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: `$(this).closest('parent').find(".wanted").html();` try this

Comment: @quill No man.@guradio As I tried to put the message in an alert window shows 'undefined'.

Comment: See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b3j3o3sj/) to prove it

Comment: Note getting "html" and 'text" are quite different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is that I cannot get the Text wanted, and I don't know if I
>   have to parse or not, even when I've already tried so. I hope you can
>   help me.

This is because you are doing `var message = $(this).parent().siblings(".wanted").html();`

$(this) -> `calling` class(grandchild)

```
$(this).parent() -> <child></child>(3rd one)
```

`$(this).parent().siblings()` will give other `<child>` elements(1st and 2nd one)

Therefore you should be doing `$(this).parent().siblings().find('.wanted')` so that it can find the grandchild inside the sibling(`<child>`).

---

Comment: Man. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` with selector `"parent"` , `.find()` with selector `".wanted"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".calling").click(function() {
    var message = $(this).closest("parent").find(".wanted").html();
    console.log(message)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<parent>
  <child>
    <grandchild class="wanted">Text</grandchild>
    <grandchild></grandchild>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild></grandchild>
    <grandchild></grandchild>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild class="calling">click</grandchild>
    <grandchild></grandchild>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: It works but as I tried to put in an alert it shows 'undefined', and once parsed it shows [object Window].

Comment: @N.Ayancan _"It works but as I tried to put in an alert it shows 'undefined', and once parsed it shows [object Window]."_ Can you reproduce `'undefined'` at `alert()` at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? Not certain how "It works" though `'undefined'` text at `alert` call?

Comment: No, it works on the demo. The thing is that I have multiple Parents and Wanted text maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the event handler just with `on()` something like:

```
$("body").on("click", ".calling", function(){
    // traverse several steps up to the parent, then back down to desired element.
    var message = $(this).parents("parent").find(".wanted").text();
});
```

From the docs:

> The `.parents()` and `.parent()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
       <child> // Child 1
           <grandchild class="wanted">Text</grandchild> // grandChild1
           <grandchild></grandchild>
       </child>
       <child> // Child 2
           <grandchild></grandchild>   // grandChild2
           <grandchild></grandchild>   // // grandChild3
       </child>
       <child> // Child 3
           <grandchild class="calling"></grandchild>   // grandChild4
           <grandchild></grandchild>   // grandChild5
       </child>
   </parent>
```

If there is a single usage of `calling` class `$('grandChild.wanted').text()` will be enough to get text inside grandChild1 on click of grandChild4 .

If there are multiple tags with same `.wanted` you have to use `.each` & `$(this).text()` to get the text content of the tag

If there are multiple `.calling` class then

```
$('.calling').on('click',function(event){
  $(this).closest('parent').find('.wanted').text().trim()
})
```

`closest()` will always travel up in the DOM tree and will match with the first matched element. `trim` is used to remove any white space

Answer (score 0):

As @Nikhilesh-k-v posted, it keeps given me the value of the three different childs, so I had to specified a little bit more. Thank you everyone, every comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to get this: see all these

```
console.clear();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".calling").on('click', function() {
    var messages = {};
    messages.message0 = $(this).parents('parent').find(".wanted").html();
    // or
    messages.message1 = $(this).parent().parent().find(".wanted").html();
    messages.message2 = $(this).parent('child').siblings().find(".wanted").html();
    messages.message3 = $(this).parent('child').siblings().find(".wanted").text();
    messages.message4 = $(this).parentsUntil('parent').siblings().find(".wanted").html();
    messages.message5 = $('parent').find(".wanted").html(); // if only ONE parent
    messages.message6 = $('parent').find("grandchild.wanted").text(); // if only ONE parent and in grandchild element
    messages.message7 = $('parent').find(".wanted").text(); // if only ONE parent
    messages.message8 = $('parent').find(".wanted").first().text(); // if first ONE present if many
    messages.message9 = $('body').find(".wanted").first().text(); // not recommended but...
    messages.message10 = $('body').find(".wanted").first().text(); // not recommended but...
    messages.message11 = $('parent').find(".wanted").first().text(); // not recommended but...
    messages.message12 = $('parent').find('child').find('grandchild').filter(".wanted").text(); // not recommended but...
    messages.message13 = $('grandchild.wanted').text(); // all of them...
    messages.message14 = $('grandchild.wanted').eq(0).text(); // first of them...
    messages.message15 = $('grandchild.wanted:first()').text(); // first of them...
    console.dir(messages);
  }).trigger('click');
});
```